# JavaScript: Detection of a link click inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, click, detection

How to detect user's click on the link inside the iframe using JavaScript?

Comment: You can only add JavaScript to the iframe if the iframe is in the same domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to check iframe load event

```
onLoad="alert(this.contentWindow.location);"
```

or on jquery:

```
$('iframe#yourId').load(function() {
  alert("the iframe has been loaded");
});
```

Comment: loading of an iframe has nothing to detect a click on a link in the iframe

Comment: why? When you clicked on link then location of iframe will be changed, so iframe load event should be fired.

Comment: Actually, that worked for me, because I don't need to detect every click inside the frame but click on the link which is equal to iframe location change. EDIT: I'm able only to accept this answer, can't vote up for some reason (didn't voted down tho).

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have an iframe with ID "myIframe", and the iframe comes from the same domain as the main document, the following will detect a click anywhere in the document. This will also work when the document is editable, which using the document's `onclick` property would not:

```
function iframeClickHandler() {
    alert("Iframe clicked");
}

var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

if (typeof iframeDoc.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    iframeDoc.addEventListener("click", iframeClickHandler, false);
} else if (typeof iframeDoc.attachEvent != "undefined") {
    iframeDoc.attachEvent ("onclick", iframeClickHandler);
}
```

Comment: this assumes the iframe is not cross domain I think.

Comment: @erikvold: Correct. I've added a note to my answer.

Comment: Any idea why it's not working on Chrome? In Firefox is fine