# Detect click outside div doesn't work if click target is iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dialog, dom-events

I've got dialog that I wrote and it closes when clicking outside (no overlay/backdrop).

It works nicely **unless** there's an iframe, in which case my listener on outside clicks is never called.

Here is [a JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vuneyopedu/edit?js,console,output) to illustrate the problem. (http://jsbin.com/vuneyopedu/edit?js,console,output)

To briefly explain in the below screenshot:

- Clicking RED Dialog Increments.
- Clicking Outside Dialog (YELLOW and GREEN) should Decrement but only YELLOW works.
- The event listener for outside clicks is never called when clicking `iframe` (GREEN)

[image: Example]

Question is - How do I make clicking **anything** outside the RED square (specifically clicking the iframe) decrement the number. (or close the dialog, in the "real" world)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about binding event to iframes' document.

```
iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
iframesArray = Array.prototype.slice.apply(iframes);

iframesArray.forEach(function(frame) {
  frame.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    inc();
  }, true);
});
```

Comment: Works nicely! Thanks!

Comment: What if the iframe is someone else's website, not your code?

Comment: this is the proper way imo, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476370/2897455

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach here is to use a modal and one of the strongest use-cases for the modal. By design modals prevent clicks from falling through to elements below hence there is no need to handle side effects like your iframe issue or `e.stopPropagation()` or anything else. It also makes positioning very clean.

*As a side note, the currently accepted answer is a very poor approach since it relies on adding an event handler inside the iFrame, then binding that onto the parent container window. This is wrong on many levels: no separation of concerns, iframe from different domains will be blocked due to CORS, iframe will register with any and all parents even when not needed, etc.*

Comment: How does a modal help negate any issues with CORS, if you wanted to capture all clicks from the inner iframe you would have to add it into the top level document.